# How to signout in access runtime 2013

Tags: ms-access, sharepoint, runtime, ms-access-2013

I have data stored in SharePoint List, and using frontend as access to filling the data and generate reports.

Users need to sign-in into access run-time to be able to connect to the SharePoint.

After signing in, How do they sign-out?

IF sign-out is not available, is there any registry value that cab be deleted, which will delete the sign-in.

Comment: The sign in is not for Access front-end but for SharePoint to be able to retrieve the data. You can close and reopen the front-end or search for  modify "linked table" connectionstring in Access.

Comment: There is an option to sign-in in access runtime, on Top Right.
Once signed in, there seems NO option to signout